# Need javascript location object data in ruby helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need a way to pass javascript object, that is `window.location.href`  into a rails helper and use the url value there.

is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: You could use `http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass the javascript value to the helper, you can use

`request.original_url` on your code, and will give you the same value as `window.location.href` in javascript